# How to use connection tag in config xml of Magento2

Tags: magento2

How do we add this to config.xml of Magento2 from the config xml of Magento1

```
<productattributesimportexport_write>
     <connection>
        <use>core_write</use>
     </connection>
</productattributesimportexport_write>
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 have concept of resource yes for interact wih database.

We need to inject the object resource  Magento\Framework\App\Resource inside di.xml

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassDelete">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="deleteorderAction" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="context" xsi:type="string">Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context</item>
            <item name="resource" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

In controller action you can use

```
protected  _resource;
public function __construct(Context $context,\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource)
{
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Now you can get resource for reading and writing

```
$connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
$showTables =$connection->fetchCol('show tables');
```

For more details [link](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-programming-get-default-core-write-and-read-resource-row-direct-sql)